# Unable to handle event by javascript in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, event-handling, contextmenu

I'm trying to remove/hide some kind of HTML elements in a web page by using Internet Explorer's standard context menu for extending an application which uses IE. To do this, I wrote a simple code like this:

```
<html>
<script language="javascript" defer>
var w=window.external.menuArguments,d=w.document,b=d.body;  
function mclick(c){
  var t=c.target||c.srcElement;
  alert(t.nodeName);
  c.preventDefault();           
  t.style.display='none';       
}
b.onclick=mclick(w.event); 
</script>
</html>
```

When the script starts, mclick function starts running immediately without any mouse click. And not triggering by any click event any more.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want `b.onclick=mclick;`. The `mclick(w.event)` is immediately calling the function.

Comment: @Bergi That's true if html file would started alone. But there is a special situation; the script has injected by Internet Explorer's standard context menu to a web page. I think that's why `b.onclick=mclick;` isn't working. I also tried `b.addEventListener('click',mclick);` but it gives neither click response nor error.

Comment: IE has been retired and ended supporting, I suggest you can focus more on modern browsers like Chrome, Microsoft Edge instead of IE.

Comment: @Xudong Peng
I think the stackoverflow exists to save people time. Thus, we will spend less time and energy on research by benefiting from the people who have experienced and resolved the same problems in the past. Such useless suggestions just wastes time. Thanks.